# Display time format data into highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I would like to plot some time data from MySQL TIME(3) format, so hh:mm:ss.fff to Highcharts.

Now I'm able to display it just with a conversion into second:

> $sql   = "select TIME_TO_SEC(time_format(TIMEZERO, '%H%:%i:%s.%f')) as
>   TIMEZERO, TIME_TO_SEC(time_format(TS, '%H%:%i:%s.%f')) as TS FROM
>   timezero ORDER BY TS";

with a JSON file that looks like this:

> [["45130","0"],["45130","0"],["45130","0"]]

but if I dont convert to seconds, they seams to be text strings :

> $sql   = "select (time_format(TIMEZERO, '%H%:%i:%s.%f')) as TIMEZERO,
>   (time_format(TS, '%H%:%i:%s.%f')) as TS FROM timezero ORDER BY TS";

JSON output:

> [["12:32:10.274000","00:00:00.000000"],["12:32:10.281000","00:00:00.000000"],["12:32:10.289000","00:00:00.000000"]]

Is there any way to keep from TIME(3) format of the original data stored in the database, and display it in to the axis labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found a way:
I get the time string from MySQL Database, than I parse in the PHP file to seconds with explode function:

> ```
>         $TIME = ($row['TIME']);
>         $SIGN = substr($row['TIME'],0,1);
>         $explode = explode(':', $TIME);
>         if (ctype_digit($SIGN)) {$TIME = +1 * (abs($explode[0]) * 3600 + $explode[1] * 60 + $explode[2]);}
>         else                    {$TIME = -1 * (abs($explode[0]) * 3600 + $explode[1] * 60 + $explode[2]);}
>         $TS    = (strtotime($row['TS'])*1000);
>         $data[] = array($TS, $TIME);
> ```

And I can plot that parsed data with both negative and positive values in seconds with also decimal digits:
Than to have back a human readable format parsing back to HH:MM:SS:F into axis properties with

> ```
>       yAxis: {
>     labels: {                
>         formatter: function () {
>       h = Math.floor(this.value / (60*60));
>       m = Math.floor(this.value / 60);
>       s = Math.floor(this.value % 60);
>       s = s % 60;
>       m = m % 60;
>       h = h % 24;
>       if (h < 9) h = "0" + h;
>       if (m < 9) m = "0" + m;
>       if (s < 9) s = "0" + s;
>       return  [h, m, s].join(':');
>         }
>     }
> },
> ```

Now I just have to find a way to plat multiple series from an imported JSON with Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question fully, but if you want to get date in custom format just get raw date from db and convert it to any date format you want with php. For ex. date("d-m-Y H:i", strtotime($rawDateFromDB));